# Su -c is not working and ignored

Tags: rhel, su

It's explained that if we using `su` with `-c` parameter it will pass the command to user's shell and execute it.

But in my environment, it totally ignore's the `-c` option and change to user's shell.

```
[root@mftf~]# su - demo -c "ls -la"

[demo@mftf~]$
```

but if I using `-c` without any command follow, it will show the error that `-c` need a argument, so it's not ignored..
I'm using RHEL 7.

Comment: Your command also works correctly for me (on a non-RHEL version of Linux). What is the login shell for `demo`?  Can you post the output for `grep demo /etc/passwd`, and, from user’s shell (`demo$ `), `ps -fp$$` and `ps -fudemo`?

Comment: @Scott-СлаваУкраїні I wish you would have posted this as an answer. I experienced the same issue as OP described and for me the problem was the login shell of the user i wanted to become (ksh, it works with bash). Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 3):

When using `-` (or `-l`) you invoke an interactive login shell for the specified user.

Depending on what the shell initialization files do for the given user, the command may not be executed.  For example, if they re-execute a shell using `exec` (without passing the command line parameters from the invoking shell), either directly or through something like `tmux` or `ssh-agent`, then the command string would be lost.

For example: I have

```
if tmux has-session; then
    exec tmux attach-session
else
    exec tmux
fi
```

... in my `~/.profile`, which is why `su -l me some_command` won't execute `some_command` (instead, an interactive shell is started inside `tmux`).

To execute a command as another user using `su` just do

```
# su -c some_command username
```

From the Ubuntu `su(1)` manual:

> `-`, `-l`, `--login`
>
> Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the
>          user logged in directly.

---

Or set up `sudo` and use

```
$ sudo -u user some_command
```

Comment: well thats bcoz profile is not loaded, so when you invoke su demo without - your current user cwd becomes cwd for user demo, so in this case /root is you cwd and hence user demo didnt had permission to access /root.

Comment: @Christopher I refined that part.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use - (hyphen) after su. Simply run 
`su demo -c 'ls -la'`
When you invoke '-' with su, It initializes user profile and environment. There must be some script within profile which is not letting user shell to reach at the end.